# Composer doctrine/orm error while resolving after a recent comming in composer.json

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php

Since a few days I'm getting this error running `composer update`. When I first setup the project all went fine but now I have an issue I can't understand or fix:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an
>   installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - doctrine/orm 2.5.x-dev requires doctrine/common >=2.5-dev,<2.6-dev -> no matching package found.
>       - doctrine/orm dev-master requires doctrine/common >=2.5-dev,<2.6-dev -> no matching package found.
>       - doctrine/orm dev-master requires doctrine/common >=2.5-dev,<2.6-dev -> no matching package found.
>       - remove doctrine/orm 2.5.x-dev|keep doctrine/orm dev-master
>       - Installation request for doctrine/orm >=2.5@dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/orm[dev-master, 2.5.x-dev].
>
> Potential causes:
>    - A typo in the package name
>    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting    see
>   https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion
>   for more details.
>
> Read http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for
>   further common problems.

Adding `"doctrine/common": ">=2.5@dev"` doesn't help.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "avalanche123/imagine-bundle": "~2.1",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.5@dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.3",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "~1.5",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "~1.5",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "dev-master",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.6",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.2",
    "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "~1",
    "ircmaxell/password-compat": "*",
},
```

**UPDATE** putting `doctrine/common` and `doctrine/dbal` to `>=2.5@dev` fixes the problem. But installing the dev-dependecies the problem is `doctrine/doctrine-fixture-bundle`:

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

> Loading composer repositories with package information Installing
>   dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be
>   resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle ~2.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle[v2.2.0].
>       - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/orm dev-master
>       - don't install doctrine/orm 2.5.x-dev|install doctrine/orm dev-master
>       - Installation request for doctrine/orm >=2.5@dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/orm[dev-master, 2.5.x-dev].

Answer (score 2):

Here you have an [answer](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2734) to a similar problem

> I suspect you have your minimum stability set to "stable", which means
> that the dev versions of DBAL and Common cannot be used to fulfill the
> requirement (while it is exactly what is needed). You have 3
> solutions:
>
> 1. Change your minimum stability when you are using unstable
>    libraries
> 2. Whitelist the dev version of DBAL and Common in your root
>    composer.json (by adding a requirement with a @dev flag)
> 3. use stable
>    versions of Doctrine (i.e. 2.4) instead of using the master branch

The problem could be related to Symfony2's doctrine bundles that are incompatible with the 2.5@dev. Even if you set minimum stability to "dev" or if you include the required dependencies manually in the root composer.json.

**UPDATE**

I've managed to run an installation of vendors with the following `composer.json` (based on yours):

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "avalanche123/imagine-bundle": "~2.1",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.5@dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.3",
        "doctrine/common": ">=2.5@dev",
        "doctrine/dbal": ">=2.5@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "~1.5",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "~1.5",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.6",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.2",
        "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "~1",
        "ircmaxell/password-compat": "*"
    },
```

I didn't run into the problem you mention in your update. Maybe you should try to do a fresh installation instead of an update. What I did (Linux Debian):

```
rm -rf vendor/ app/cache/ app/logs/ composer.lock
composer install
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Even adding doctrine/orm and doctrine/common to ">=2.5@dev" can't fix that. I think the problem is doctrine/doctrine-fixture-bundle (dev-requirement). See my edit, thanks.